# Dropping upper limit element of binomial distribution function index summation

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Does anyone know how it is possible to lose the n element in the index of the summation, while remaining equal ?

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}q^kp^{n-k}(n-k)^1 = np\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}q^kp^{n-k-1}
$$

I understand the following steps

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}q^kp^{n-k+1-1}(n-k)^1
$$

$$
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)^{1}(n-k-1)!}q^kp^{n-k-1}p^{1}(n-k)^1
$$

Comment: Your second equation has some typos in it, but if you straighten that out, it should be fine. The last term disappears simply because when $k=n$, $n-k=0$

Comment: $\binom{n-1}n=0$